# len function gives two excess length

Tags: c, numbers

i have my length  function to calculate the length of array, but it is giving two excess garbage numbers(negative). It must return 6 but it returns 8 due to garbage values.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int length(int *arr) {
    int _length = 0;
    while (*arr) {
        _length++;
        arr++;
    }
    return _length; 
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    printf("%d\n", length(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `length` function is assuming that the array is null-terminated. But `arr` isn't null-terminated. So you have undefined behavior.

Comment: All the `length` function have is a pointer to a single `int` valiue. There's no way for the function to find the "end" of the array. All it does it go out of bounds and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't use identifiers starting with `_` (like `_length`), they are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Also think a little, what if you passed an array with a *zero* in it to the function? If arrays were truly zero-terminated, how would your function differ between a zero in the array and the zero-terminator?

Comment: Isnt null character only used in array of character only?

Comment: @Anonymous what happens if `arr` should contain the value 0?

Comment: @Anonymous It is convention that strings are null-terminated (string literals are also null-terminated and the standard library assumes this as well). For other kinds of arrays this is _sometimes_ used (e.g. when passing an array of pointers it is somewhat common), but not in general. In particular a null-terminated array cannot contain any other null value, limiting the use cases.

Comment: It's a standardized convention that strings in C are zero-terminated. That only applies to *null-terminated strings*, not to arrays in general. You could actually have an array of character that are *not* null-terminated. You can't pass it to any function expecting a null-terminated string, but it's still a valid array of characters.

Comment: Maybe you want `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)` which will give you the size of the `arr` array in number of elements. Be aware that this won't work if `arr` is a _pointer_.

Comment: Note that the above will only work in the scope where the array was declared.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I think `_` followed by lower-case letter is only reserved for external identifiers.

Comment: `int arr[] = {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0};` you may even add more numbers: `int arr[] = {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 2022, -1, 42};`

Comment: Debug fail:(   printffing out _length and *arr in the loop would have shown up your problem:((

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need some manner of termination condition. `while (*arr)` assumes that the array ends with zero which isn't the case, so you simply can't have a loop like that.

The size of this array is known at compile time so there's no need to calculate anything in run-time.
`(sizeof arr / sizeof *arr)` gives you the number of items in the array, as long as you place that code in the same scope as the array declaration.

Also, using that `sizeof` trick (which is an idiomatic way of determining the size) inside a function-like macro is a common solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define length(arr) (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr))

int main() {
    int arr[] = {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    printf("%zu\n", length(arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To readers of this answer: The part that say "in the same scope as the array declaration" is *very* important! Once you pass an array to a function it has decayed to a pointer to the arrays first element, and the size of the array is lost. Doing `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the actual pointer itself, not to what it might point to.

Comment: Better to use `(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*(arr)))` (add ()) to maintain precedence.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Not really since any possible postfix operator passed to the macro will screw everything up regardless of that extra parenthesis.